# GWT Java error with AsyncCallback within a method

Tags: java, asynchronous, gwt, methods

On the client side I am placing a call to the server side for a list of names from the database. When this list is returned to the client side I display each name in a TabPanel. As each name is displayed I place a call to the server side for a list of addresses for that name from the database on the server side (this is so I can update and add). When the list of addresses is returned I add them to a FlexTable inside a DisclosurePanel.

So I have a TabPanel containing a name and a DisclosurePanel containing the associated addresses.

The issue is that I can not get the call to the database, in the DisclosurePanel method, to get the addresses correct.

The code is:

```
private DisclosurePanel addressDisclosurePanel(String nameId) {
    DisclosurePanel addressDisclosurePanel = new DisclosurePanel("Address");

    //Get the Addresses
    AsyncCallback<List<Address>> callback = new GetAddressHandler<List<Address>>();
    rpc.getAddressList(nameId, callback);


    class GetAddressHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<List<Address>> {
        //Get the list of Addresses.
        PersonalDetailsView view;

        public GetAddressHandler(PersonalDetailsView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("RPC call failed - GetAddressHandler - Notify Administrator.");
            Window.alert("Connection failed - please retry.");
        }
        public void onSuccess(List<Address> result) {
            view.renderAddresses(result);
        }
    }

    public void renderAddresses(List<Address> addressList) {
        //Load each TabPanel with Addresses

        final FlexTable flexTableAddress = new FlexTable();

        if (addressList == null || addressList.isEmpty()) {
            //Add a place to add an address

            //Address Type
            final Label lblAddressType = new Label("Address Type:");
            lblAddressType.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
            flexTableAddress.setWidget(0, 0, lblAddressType);

            final TextBox textBoxAddressType = new TextBox();
            textBoxAddressType.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
            textBoxAddressType.setWidth("300px");
            flexTableAddress.setWidget(0, 1, textBoxAddressType);

            addressDisclosurePanel.add(flexTableAddress);

        }else{
            int row = 0;
            //
            //Create a place to display each Address and allow update
            //
            for (final Address eachAddress : addressList) {
                //Store key
                final String addId = eachAddress.getAddId();

                //Address Type
                final Label lblAddressType = new Label("Address Type:");
                lblAddressType.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
                flexTableAddress.setWidget(row, 0, lblAddressType);

                final TextBox textBoxAddressType = new TextBox();
                textBoxAddressType.setText(eachAddress.getAddType());
                textBoxAddressType.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                textBoxAddressType.setWidth("300px");
                flexTableAddress.setWidget(row, 1, textBoxAddressType);

                row++;
            }
            addressDisclosurePanel.add(flexTableAddress);
        }
    }
    return addressDisclosurePanel;
}
```

The error is on the line:

```
view.renderAddresses(result);
```

The error message is "The method renderAddresses(List) is undefined for the type PersonalDetailsView".

An on the line:

```
public void renderAddresses(List<Address> addressList) {
```

The error message is "Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    - void is an invalid type for the variable 
     renderAddresses"

I made this change:

```
    private DisclosurePanel addressDisclosurePanel(String nameId) {
    final DisclosurePanel addressDisclosurePanel = new DisclosurePanel("Address");

    //Get the Addresses
    AsyncCallback<List<Address>> callback = new GetAddressHandler<List<Address>>(PersonalDetailsView.this);
    rpc.getAddressList(nameId, callback);

    //addressDisclosurePanel.add(addressHorizontalPanel);

    return addressDisclosurePanel;
}

class GetAddressHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<List<Address>> {
    //Get the list of Addresses.
    PersonalDetailsView view;

    final HorizontalPanel addressHorizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

    public GetAddressHandler(PersonalDetailsView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("RPC call failed - GetAddressHandler - Notify Administrator.");
        Window.alert("Connection failed - please retry.");
    }
    public void onSuccess(List<Address> result) {
        Window.alert("Render address.");
        addressHorizontalPanel.add(view.renderAddresses(result));
    }
}

private FlexTable renderAddresses(List<Address> addressList) {
    //Load each TabPanel with Addresses
    Window.alert("get address.");;

    final FlexTable flexTableAddress = new FlexTable();

    if (addressList == null || addressList.isEmpty()) {
        //Add a place to add an address

        //Address Type
        final Label lblAddressType = new Label("Address Type:");
        lblAddressType.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
        flexTableAddress.setWidget(0, 0, lblAddressType);

        final TextBox textBoxAddressType = new TextBox();
        textBoxAddressType.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
        textBoxAddressType.setWidth("300px");
        flexTableAddress.setWidget(0, 1, textBoxAddressType);

    }else{
        int row = 0;
        //
        //Create a place to display each Address and allow update
        //
        for (final Address eachAddress : addressList) {
            //Store key
            final String addId = eachAddress.getAddId();
            Window.alert("addId = " + addId);

            //Address Type
            final Label lblAddressType = new Label("Address Type:");
            lblAddressType.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
            flexTableAddress.setWidget(row, 0, lblAddressType);

            final TextBox textBoxAddressType = new TextBox();
            textBoxAddressType.setText(eachAddress.getAddType());
            textBoxAddressType.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
            textBoxAddressType.setWidth("300px");
            flexTableAddress.setWidget(row, 1, textBoxAddressType);

            row++;
        }
    }
    return flexTableAddress;
}
```

So how do I return the address from:

```
class GetAddressHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<List<Address>> {
```

to the DisclosurePanel?

Comment: You can not declare a class inside of a method

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare a class inside of a method. So Change:

```
   //Get the Addresses
    AsyncCallback<List<Address>> callback = new GetAddressHandler<List<Address>>();
    rpc.getAddressList(nameId, callback);


    class GetAddressHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<List<Address>> {
        //Get the list of Addresses.
        PersonalDetailsView view;

        public GetAddressHandler(PersonalDetailsView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("RPC call failed - GetAddressHandler - Notify Administrator.");
            Window.alert("Connection failed - please retry.");
        }
        public void onSuccess(List<Address> result) {
            view.renderAddresses(result);
        }
    }
```

to:

```
//Get the Addresses
AsyncCallback<List<Address>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<Address>> {
    //Get the list of Addresses.
    PersonalDetailsView view;

    public GetAddressHandler(PersonalDetailsView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("RPC call failed - GetAddressHandler - Notify Administrator.");
        Window.alert("Connection failed - please retry.");
    }
    public void onSuccess(List<Address> result) {
        view.renderAddresses(result);
    }
}
    rpc.getAddressList(nameId, callback);
```

Hope there is no Syntax error in my edit ;)

Comment: I have applied this change and have a few errors. rpc.getAddressList(nameId, callback); - callback cannot be resolved to a variable. Should AsyncCallback<List<Address>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<Address>> include (PersonalDetailsView.this) at the end. That is how all my other calls are. This was removed earlier when I accepted a system suggestion. Maybe it should be added back? When I added it back there were a few less errors; however still errors.

Comment: And what are the Errors?

Comment: Actually yes you can declare a class inside a method. But you cannot declare a method/function within a method.

Comment: Hi @ThomasBroyer do you now how to correct this issue?

Comment: If I read your original code correctly, your `renderAddresses` was declared inside the `addressDisclosurePanel` method. Move it out to the class.

Comment: Hi @ThomasBroyer, I have put my latest code attempt above. So how do I return the address from:

    class GetAddressHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<List<Address>> {

to the DisclosurePanel?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this can be found at: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!topic/google-web-toolkit/taQlLOMZ3zw